# Solvable Lie groups acts on spheres

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups

Is there any connected solvable Lie group acts transitively on the sphere $\mathbb S^2$?

Comment: Hint: Every solvable Lie group $G$ is aspherical: $\pi_i(G)=0$ for $i\ge 2$. Now, think about homotopy groups of the fibration $G\to G/H$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. In fact, I will prove more:

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $G\times M\to M$ is a continuous transitive action of a connected Lie group, where  $M$ is any non-aspherical manifold (universal cover is not contractible). Then $G$ cannot be solvable.

**Proof.** Pick $x\in M$ and let $H<G$ denote the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$; it is a closed subgroup of $G$; necessarily a Lie subgroup. Then the orbit map $g\mapsto gx$ defines a continuous bijection $G/H\to M$. This bijection is actually a homeomorphism. (This follows from the fact that $G/H$ is a manifold, but is true in greater generality of metrizable topological spaces and locally compact group actions.)   Hence, we can identify $M$ with the base of a principal $H$-bundle $G\to M$ (with fibers homeomorphic to $H$). Now, apply the long exact sequence of homotopy groups to this bundle:
$$
...\to \pi_{i}(H)\to \pi_i(G)\to \pi_i(M)\to \pi_{i-1}(H) \to ...
$$
If $G$ were a solvable Lie group, we would have $\pi_k(G)=0$ for all $k\ge 2$ (this is a corollary of Malcev's theorem, 1945). Since $H$ is also a solvable subgroup, we have $\pi_i(G)=\pi_{i-1}(H)=0$, $i\ge 3$.

Now, if $M=S^2$ as in your question, we would conclude from this that 
$\pi_3(M)=0$. But $\pi_3(S^2)\cong {\mathbb Z}$. A contradiction.

More generally, since $M$ is not aspherical, $\pi_i(M)\ne 0$ for some $i\ge 3$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207448/simply-connected-cw-complex-with-only-finitely-many-nontrivial-homotopy-and-homo).  We again get a contradiction. qed

Comment: For the case $i=2$, one can avoid refer to the topological fact on non-aspherical finite CW-complexes. Indeed, one can suppose that $G$ is simply connected, and then use the fact that any closed subgroup of a simply connected solvable Lie group has a trivial $\pi_1$.